# How to render widget from razor view

Tags: razor, widget, orchardcms

Due to the structure of my theme (and probably to the fact that I'm quite new with Orchard), I need to render a widget from a razor view. The widget contains a secondary menu and I need to place it in the Layout.cshtml; something like this but with a widget (or a menu) instead of Model.Navigation.

```
<div id="MenuH">
    @if (Model.Navigation != null) 
        {@Display(Model.Navigation)}
</div>
```

Is this possible?

**Edit**

I need to show a secondary menu (or a widget) in this section of my Layout.cshtml "master page":

```
<section class="main-content-zone">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas">
        <<div class="col-lg-sp-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4" id="bt-sidebar">
            <div id="MenuV">
                <script type="text/javascript">$("#MenuV").html($("#MenuH nav").parent().html());</script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-sp-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" id="bt-content" role="main">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="bt-content" role="main">
                <div class="card no-margin-top show-overflow">
                    <div class="row">

                        @if (Model.Content != null){<div class="col-md-12" runat="server" id="Content">@Display(Model.Content)</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The menu/widget should go where the theme (I bought a theme) insert the js script.

Comment: Yes you can do that, call Display.Widget(). Orchard will look for the template called widget.cshtml.

Comment: 'render a widget', do you mean render a all-code widget or do you want to place a widget you added through the admin ui?

Comment: @devqon I mean a widget (or a menu) that I added through the admin UI

Comment: then you only need to define a zone, where the widget in the admin UI is added: `@Zone(Model.MyZoneName)` and in the admin UI add the widget to 'MyZoneName'

Comment: I bought a theme with some zones defined, and I was trying to avoid redefining its zones. The theme uses a Layout.html "master page" that insert two colums in the Content zone, and I need to inject a menu in the left column

Comment: @mberacochea I tried @Display.Widget("myWidget") but I get a runtime binding error (Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference)

Comment: it would be @Display.myWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to add a widget to a new zone that does not exist yet. There are a few things you need to do to achieve that:

1 Find the place in Layout.cshtml where you want to render your widgets. Define a new zone name in there:

```
<div class="col-lg-sp-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4" id="bt-sidebar">
    <div class="column-left-zone">
        @Zone(Model.ColumnLeft)
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: This assumes that your Layout.cshtml has a function defined [like this](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Themes/TheThemeMachine/Views/Layout.cshtml#L21). If not, you can just do `@Display(Model.ColumnLeft)`

2 Define the zone in your Theme.txt so that you can add widgets to it through the admin UI:

```
Zones: Header, Navigation, ..., ColumnLeft
```

3 Now the 'ColumnLeft' zone is available in your admin UI. Add your widget in the admin ui to the ColumnLeft zone